# Referencing the foreign key of another schema

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

For my project I am using oracle database where I have to work with 2 different database schema. Consider the following scenario please -

I have a schema `A` and in it I have a table `table_a` with a primary key `apk`

And I have another schema `B` and in it I have a table `table_b` with a primary key `bpk`

If both of these tables are in a same database then I can easily make a primary key - foreign key relationship.

But can I make a primary key - foreign key relation ship (or something like this) between these two columns - `A.table_a.apk` and `B.table_b.pbk`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using "database" in the Oracle sense, no you cannot create foreign keys that reference tables in a remote database.  If you really have two different schemas in the same database (`A` and `B`) then you can create a foreign key.

Comment: Databases aren't supposed to talk to each other like that. Why do you have two distinct database if you expect them to communicate?

Comment: @Justine Cave, I am using a single database. No remote database are here, I have two different schema. I will edit the question. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a foreign key that references an object in a different schema, you just need to qualify the object name

```
ALTER TABLE B.table_b
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_b_a FOREIGN KEY (apk) REFERENCES a.table_a( apk )
```

This also requires that the user `B` has sufficient privileges on `A.table_a`.  The user would need to have the `REFERENCES` privilege and would, presumably, need to have the `SELECT` privilege on the table as well.

Comment: What are those sufficient  privilèges on A.table_a ?
Responce : "grant references on A.table_a to B";

Comment: What if the schema is not know ahead of time, but is "dynamic", e.g. it is located on a column on `table_b`?

Comment: @EgeErsoz - I'm not sure that I follow.  If you don't know when you are defining the child table which schema has the parent table that it needs to reference, then you can't create a constraint (and you have a very problematic data model).  Is that what you are asking?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Under the public schema, I have `table_a`, which contains two columns: `invoice_id` and `schema_name`. I want to tell Postgres that `invoice_id` refers to `schema_name.invoices`, where `schema_name` is the column value in that row. Does that make sense?

Comment: For instance, if `invoice_id` is "2452" and `schema_name` is "acme_inc", then I want Postgres to establish the reference _dynamically_, i.e. tie that row to `acme_inc.invoices` table. This is so that if Invoice 2452 under `acme_inc.invoices` is deleted, it can cascade and delete its child record under `public.invoices`.

I can establish the relationship in reverse, i.e. have a `public_invoice_id` column under `schema_name.invoices" that refers to the `public.invoices` table, but then cascade doesn't work, and I end up having to delete the public invoice manually.

Comment: @ege ersoz- I don’t expect that to be possible.  I’m not a Postgres expert but I have never seen any database that would do that.  It seems like a very, very odd way to design a data model

Comment: Thanks Justin. I guess I was out of topic anyway. Apologies.