# How to reference foreign key of another schema table while creating table?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, sql-grant

I have two Schemas :-

- GamersProfileDB  - Contain `UserCredential_tbl` table
- DeveloperDB      - Contain `PlayerAchievements_tbl` table

Now while creating table called `PlayerAchievements_tbl` , i want to reference it from another schema table  `Usercredential_tbl`  . Here is the following sql query :-

```
create table PlayerAchievements_tbl 
(
pid number(10) references gamersprofiledb.usercredential (id),
aid number(10) references achievements (id) 
);
```

But the above query gave me ***'table or view does not exist'*** error

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155012/referencing-the-foreign-key-of-another-schema?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (possible duplicate) answer adding foreign_key in ALTER operation whereas i want it to add foreign_key on CREATE TABLE operation and Moreover it also didn't specify what grants or privileges may require to  execute this query

So my exact question would be :-

1) could it be possible to reference another schema table into existing schema table while creating new table ?

2) or do we need some privileges to execute this query ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Other User (gamersprofiledb)  should grant permission to the current schema that you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an (unprivileged) user has no permissions to see objects owned by another user. You need to `GRANT` the privilege using:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON GamersProfileDB.UserCredential TO DeveloperDB;
```

or, if you also need to `SELECT` from the table then:

```
GRANT SELECT ON GamersProfileDB.UserCredential TO DeveloperDB;
```

Once you have permissions to reference (or select) the table then you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE PlayerAchievements_tbl                  -- Why add the "_tbl" suffix?
(
  pid number(10)
      CONSTRAINT PlayerAchievements__PID__FK         -- name the constraint
        REFERENCES GamersProfileDB.UserCredential (id),
  aid number(10)
      CONSTRAINT PlayerAchievements__AID__FK         -- name the constraint
        REFERENCES Achievements (id),
  CONSTRAINT PlayerAchievements__PID_AID__PK
    PRIMARY KEY ( pid, aid )
);
```

Comment: By the way , i always add nameless  foreign_key and primary_key .  so does it have any importance to define name with foreign_key and primary_key ?

Comment: @burhanuddinabbas Don't do that - when you get a message saying that constraint `SYS_C0123456` was violated it is not helpful. It is much more useful to know the table name, column(s) and constraint type and if you name the constraint around that information then you can see it at a glance in the exception.